# How to shadow page and show a loading div when ajax is called

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading, shadow

i want to shadow all the page when user clicks a button, show a div in the center of page with a loading gif and call an ajax request to a page. When ajax finishes hide shadow, hide loading div. is possible? can someone explain me how?
i see [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/display-loading-gif-image-while-loading.html) this code:$

```
("#btnLoad").click(function(){

  // Put an animated GIF image insight of content
  $("#content").empty().html('<img src="loading.gif" />');

  // Make AJAX call
  $("#content").load("http://example.com");
});
```

can i use this? where i can take shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create new div (id: loader) with css: position: fixed; z-index: 90; top: 0; left: 0; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); Put it at the and of the body section
2. Create new div with css: margin: 30% auto; width: 200px; height: 60px; background: #fff; Put it into div created in first point. Put into it text 'Loading...' or sth else.
3. Create js functions which will show div from first point at start loading and hide it at the end of the loading.

E.g.

```
function loadingOn() {
    $('#loader').fadeIn(300);
}

function loadingOff() {
    $('#loader').fadeOut(300);
}

function loadingToggle() {
    $('#loader').fadeToggle(300);
}
```

You must only call that functions when you need it :)

Comment: There are very good jQuery methods called $.ajaxStart() and $.ajaxStop(). Both of them are described in jQuery API service. ([link](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [link](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/))

Comment: While accepting this answer, I don't think this is going to solve a larger problem with his execution,even though your answer is correct. And now he's creating his own 'plugin' for jQuery without actually syntactically getting it right. This may be clean for now, but will cause a massive headache in overhead. I mean he's already loading in the entire jQuery library... so why not?

Comment: A small addition to the suggested code in this solution:

You might want to add also the following CSS definitions to the main DIV of the shadow element:

width: 100%;
height: 100%;

This is done for covering the entire page content with the semi-transparent shadow thingy.

Answer (score 1):

---

Look up colorbox for jQuery. This will do everything you want with a simple light weight library addition to jQuery which you're already using.

http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: this is only for shadow.. and to add it on ajax request? hide it on ajax finish? :)

Comment: you can do all that and more! It's a pretty neat little tool. You can either load in a page from an ajax request, or you can populate the html as a property... give it a look, you can also turn on and off shadows, and use the call backs to make things happen early or late to get the desired effect you've described above.